# React Native check if I have permission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, permissions, native

I have written an app which records audio and do real time analysis. For this I must first request permission to use the microphone so I have made a separate button for this but I don't like the solution. The button runs this function:

```js
const requestMicrophone = async () => {
  //replace your function with this code.
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
        {
          title: 'Permissions for record audio',
          message: 'Give permission to your device to record audio',
          buttonPositive: 'ok',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('permission granted');
      } else {
        console.log('permission denied');
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

Now I want to check if I have permission to use the microphone. If so render the recording component. I tried this:

```js
if (PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO) {
      rec = <Recorder/>;
    } else {
      rec = <Text>Ask for microphone permission first!</Text>;
    }
```

However this does not check if I have permission to use the microphone. What I get from

```js
console.log(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO);
```

is just

```
[Wed Nov 18 2020 18:59:44.878]  LOG      android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

I just cannot find anywhere how to check if I do have permission to use the microphone or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer after much googling around:

```
export const checkMicrophone = async () => {
   const result = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
   );
   return result;
};
```